# Add protocol conformance for Collection of a specific type

Tags: swift

I'd like to add protocol conformance to `Collection` when `Element` is a specific type.

As an example of what I'm trying to do, consider the (contrived) code below for binding numeric values to placeholders in an expression.

```swift
typealias Placeholder = String

enum Number {
    case integer(Int64)
    case float(Double)
}

protocol Bindable {
    func bind(to expression: Expression, for placeholder: Placeholder)
}

class Expression {
    var values: [Placeholder: Number] = [:]
}

extension Int: Bindable {
    func bind(to expression: Expression, for placeholder: Placeholder) {
        expression.values[placeholder] = .integer(Int64(self))
    }
}

extension Float: Bindable {
    func bind(to expression: Expression, for placeholder: Placeholder) {
        expression.values[placeholder] = .float(Double(self))
    }
}

class Builder {
    let expression = Expression()
    func set<T: Bindable>(_ value: T, for placeholder: Placeholder) {
        value.bind(to: expression, for: placeholder)
    }
}
```

With this code it's possible to set `Int` and `Float` values:

```swift
let builder = Builder()
builder.set(Int(10), for: "Int")
builder.set(Float(10), for: "Float")
```

Now I'd like to be able to use the existing `set(_:for:)` to bind the sum of an array when `Element` is `Int`:

```swift
extension Bindable where Self: Collection, Element == Int {
    func bind(to expression: Expression, for placeholder: Placeholder) {
        expression.values[placeholder] = .integer(Int64(self.reduce(0, +)))
    }
}

// Error: Instance method 'set(_:for:)' requires that '[Int]' conform to 'Bindable'
builder.set([1,2], for: "sum")
```

I incorrectly assumed that the extension would make `[Int]` conform to `Bindable`.

I can work around the problem by adding an additional `set(_:for:)` function to `Builder`:

```swift
class Builder {
    func set<T: Collection>(_ value: T, for placeholder: Placeholder) where T.Element == Int {
        value.bind(to: expression, for: placeholder)
    }
}

extension Collection where Element == Int {
    func bind(to expression: Expression, for placeholder: Placeholder) {
        expression.values[placeholder] = .integer(Int64(self.reduce(0, +)))
    }
}

builder.set([1,2], for: "sum")
```

But I'd like to understand why the first method doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You thought that this makes all `[Int]` conform to `Bindable`:

```
extension Bindable where Self: Collection, Element == Int {
```

What the above actually says is:

> Add this `bind` method to all conformers of `Bindable`, that is also a collection of `Int`.

You are extending the wrong thing. You should be writing an extension on `[Int]`, not conformers of `Bindable`. You want to say:

> Add this `bind` method to all collection of `Int` (and also conform it to `Bindable`)

```
extension Collection : Bindable where Element == Int {
    func bind(to expression: Expression, for placeholder: Placeholder) {
        expression.values[placeholder] = .integer(Int64(self.reduce(0, +)))
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't actually work... because unfortunately, you can't make a protocol conform to another protocol via an extension, so the next alternative is to do it for arrays:

```
extension Array : Bindable where Element == Int {
    func bind(to expression: Expression, for placeholder: Placeholder) {
        expression.values[placeholder] = .integer(Int64(self.reduce(0, +)))
    }
}
```

---

If you really want `set` to accept a generic collection/sequence, you could add another overload for `set` that accepts `Sequence`s:

```
func set<S, T>(_ values: S,
               for placeholder: Placeholder,
               withIdentity identity: T,
               andReductionFunction reductionFunction: (T, S.Element) -> T)
    where S: Sequence, S.Element: Bindable, T: Bindable {
    values.reduce(identity, reductionFunction).bind(to: expression, for: placeholder)
}
```

Usage:

```
builder.set([1,2], for: "sum", withIdentity: 0, andReductionFunction: +)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the first method you mentioned initially which obviously didn't work. It seems the real answer is that it can't be done, right now at least. Maybe in a future Swift version!

Comment: @sbooth If you just want `set` to be able to accept `Collection`s, you could just add another overload. See the edit.

Comment: There is a mention of this in https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md#extending-protocols-to-conform-to-protocols and it seems the Swift team thought this would introduce more problems than it would solve.